# Regex to search mongo database for emails

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

Im not too good with regular expressions, but I need a regular expression to do a mongo search in php for emails in a string like this:

```
[to]=>'jfields@example.com, lknight@example.com, sbeltran@example.com, ltran@example.com'
```

My specific problem is that I can't get a expression to work to find specifically `ltran@example.com` but not `sbeltran@example.com`.
I used something like this `['$regex'] = new MongoRegex("/(\W)(".$email.")/");` but then this doesn't find `jfields@example.com` because it has no space in front of it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: No it isn't, OP wants to search the `to` field for a specific address. `to` fields contains a comma/space separated list of email addresses.

Comment: normalize the db, you shouldn't have multiple addresses in one filed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
$email_quoted = preg_quote($email, '#');
$regex = "#\b$email_quoted\b#";
```

There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.